# How can i run another api after i get the response for current api in postman

Tags: postman

Good afternoon. Please help me in the below scenario,
I have two api: 1) ABC api 2) XYZ api
ABC api alters the output of XYZ api, I create a collection and add this two api in this collection, and I want the execution sequence like below:

1. Execute the ABC api and get the response, but before I run a test script related to ABC api I want to run XYZ api.
2. Execute XYZ api.
3. Start executing the test script of ABC api which is not executed in sequence 1.

How can I achieve this sequence using postman?

If the question is not clear please let me know, I will try to be more descriptive,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Pre-request Script" you can make a call to your abc API. And set it to a variable.
[image]

Like :

```
const response = await fetch(httpAdressAsString);
```

Or use the snippet of Postman:

```
pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply,but my problem is still not resolved,ABC api alter the o/p of XYZ api so i have to verify the XYZ api in ABC test script so before executhing the test script of ABC,XYZ api should get run so i can able to verify the o/p of XYZ api in test script of ABC